# Full browser width bar using negative margins

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/#article-header-id-0

What I need, is my `<header>` element to be a *max-width* of 800px, centered in the middle of the page. Then inside that header bar, I will be having a **#filtersBar** div that will go across the whole body of the page (edge to edge). This is what my code comes out with so far:

[image]

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/us2jsmLy/3/

```css
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  z-index: 250;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background:red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#filtersBar {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 -9999rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 9999rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

#filtersBarInner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>
  foo bar some contents
  <div id="filtersBar">
    <div id="filtersBarInner">
      dddd
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I must be missing something stupid :/

Comment: Can you try to explain why what you wrote isn't what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you can use `:before` pseudo for the full background edge to edge and also apply `margin:0` to body

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0L4yqp4u/)**

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

div#filtersBar:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -1000px;
  right: -1000px;
  z-index: -1;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  z-index: 250;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#filtersBar {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

#filtersBarInner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>
  foo bar some contents
  <div id="filtersBar">
    <div id="filtersBarInner">
      <p>
        ddddd
      </p>
      <p>
        ddddd
      </p>
      <p>
        ddddd
      </p>
      <p>
        ddddd
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: thanks, thats almost it :) http://www.ultranerds.co.uk/test/ ... for some reason the "filters bar" bit doesn't show though (if you inspect `#filtersBar` you can see where there text SHOULD be, but for some reason it doesn't actually show?). Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewNewby apply  `z-index: -1` to `:before`...Updated

Comment: You legend - that was it :) I was playing with `z-index` on the other divs, but didn't think to try it on the `::before`